# Anti-sniffer for USB

Tags: sniffer, keyloggers, usb

I'm looking for a Windows utility that can list all drivers, driver-filters, services, sniffers and other information for a selected USB port.

I want to check if my "USB connection" is confidential.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for strange USB device IDs with USBDview or USBView.

> USBDeview is a small utility that lists all USB devices that currently
>   connected to your computer, as well as all USB devices that you
>   previously used.  For each USB device, extended information is
>   displayed: Device name/description, device type, serial number (for
>   mass storage devices), the date/time that device was added, VendorID,
>   ProductID, and more...  USBDeview also allows you to uninstall USB
>   devices that you previously used, disconnect USB devices that are
>   currently connected to your computer, as well as to disable and enable
>   USB devices.
>   [image]

[USB View](http://k0lee.com/dc3000/usbts.htm) is similar.
[image]

Other methods to defeat hardware key-loggers:

- while typing sensitive information like passwords, after a few keys
  of the password, use your mouse and point to a different location the
  type some keys and then go back to the password field. This ways the
  key logger doesn't know which keys are useful and which are not
- use a password manager like LastPAss that fills in passwords
- use a virtual on screen keyboard
- use one time passwords or security tokens to make your passwords unique

usean on screen keyboard for sensitive data

Comment: But I don't mean keyloggers. I mean usb traffic in general. If I have hardware+driver and I want to check if any soft listening this traffic (As I understand it is possible to write driver-filter and receive the same data as target driver)

Comment: Then please update your question with clarifications and consider moving it to StackOverflow if you require programming advice.